# Process history in Unix/Linux systems

Tags: process, logs, ps

I know that `ps -efl` shows running processes on *nix systems.

I would like to check history of the (past) processes that have been run on a particular machine, preferably with all the information `ps` provides (i.e. `%CPU`, `%MEM`).

What command line utilities can I use, is this information stored somewhere similarly to `.bash_history` file?

Comment: On _*nix_, that's rather be `ps -efl`. `ps aux` for BSD/Linux only.

Comment: You could potentially setup SNMP and something to poll the SNMP daemon periodically to achieve this. I have done this for Memory usage for processes over a time period.

Comment: as described here: http://serverfault.com/questions/386956/pid-history-of-a-process, some processes publish there PIDs to syslog (or can be made to do so).

Answer (score 8):

Try `atop`. It can keep a configurable history of various system information (processes, and CPU, memory, disk and network usage). Note: it cannot record everything, of course; it just takes "snapshots" periodically.

EDIT: In case this is not clear, there is an `atop` daemon that does the periodical snapshots, stored in `/var/log/atop` (directory used under Debian).

Comment: Maybe noteworthy: it can't look into the past, it only sees processes while it is running.

Comment: @guntbert Since it periodically saves what it sees and one can replay that with the `-r` option, it's a way to look into the past.

Comment: True (that's why I said "maybe"), but that of course works only after having started the service, whereas the OP might be expecting to see what happened even before.

Answer (score 4):

You could give [execsnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/execsnoop) a shot. It's more reliable than the "sampling" method that `atop` adopts when it comes to log those transient processes. It does not record as much information as `ps`, like CPU and memory usage, though.

See:

- https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-28/execsnoop-for-linux.html
- https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools
- https://github.com/iovisor/bcc

Edit: since `execsnoop` is essentially a python script and it already parses out the pid (see [the source code](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/f458c3535b5d56b9e0f2841d4f42ba6951aa30bc/tools/execsnoop.py#L290)), you might tweak the script with [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) to print out CPU and memory usage if really needed.