# Check if a program/script was run at startup?

Tags: linux, startup, autostart

In Linux, there are many files we can modify to add a program run at start up (/etc/rc.local, bashrc, bash_profile, $HOME/.config/autostart, ...) ? Now I have a reverse question: I have a program, can I check if this program was run during start up?

> **Note: The program can run once at start up and exit

Comment: With systemd, if it was started as a service you can read the journal.

Comment: Thanks @jasonwryan. That's not cover my case. The program can run just by you execute it,

Comment: Then, unless it includes a logging facility, how would you expect to be able to determine if it ran or not?

Comment: I suggest expanding your question. This looks like X-Y question. Why would you want to check that? Is this check looking for some speciifc program?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the *access time* for the script.  This isn't 100% reliable (since some filesystems can have `noatime` set).  But it's usually useful for init-scripts, e.g.,

```
find /etc -type f -atime -1
```

I've found it useful for [quite a while](http://invisible-island.net/personal/paperstuff.html#t1987).

Answer (score 1):

`pstree` will give you a detailed output of process running in a tree format.

Sample output here

`init─┬─auditd───{auditd}
     ├─crond
     ├─docker─┬─10*[bash]
     │        ├─docker───5*[{docker}]
     │        ├─docker───4*[{docker}]
     │        ├─2*[docker───3*[{docker}]]
     │        ├─start-app.sh─┬─java───40*[{java}]
     │        │              └─tail
     │        ├─start-app.sh─┬─java───81*[{java}]
     │        │              └─tail`

Comment: This assumes the process is still running...

Comment: Thanks @Kailas. Same as jasonwwryan said, this must assume that the process is still running.

Comment: The same informatoin can be output with stock `ps`: `ps auf`, or on modern systems with `systemctl status` - if the process is still running.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the next command:

```
ps aux | grep PROCESS_NAME
```

For example for a `ping` process, the result will be:

```
user  9639  0.0  0.0   6508   732 pts/16   S+   08:44   0:00 ping 192.168.0.1
user  9641  0.0  0.1  12972  2420 pts/15   R+   08:44   0:00 grep --colour=auto ping
```

If you only get the second line, it means that the process is not running.

If you suspect that the process is crashing, you could use `atop`, you can find another question about `atop` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146313/process-history-in-unix-linux-systems).

Comment: Thanks @Murillo. But that is not my case, because a program can run and exit immediately so if you can't check it in process management information information

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the init locations and see if the program is set there to run.

Honestly, if the program somehow *could* run, but you don't know whether it run or not, the only chance of seeing if it did run is to either check if it had a way to run(e.g. was registered in some `local.rc` or such), or by checking the results(e.g. the program always touches file `/home/someuser/a`, and nothing else should have touched it).

The above assumes you don't have any logs.